# Template partial specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Can somebody explain why are those two specializations indistinguishable to the compiler (gcc 4.5.1 @ ideone)

http://ideone.com/9tNux

```
template <typename... T> struct S;

template<typename A, typename B, typename... C>
struct S<A, B, C...> {
   int f() {return 1;}
};

template<typename... A, typename... C>
struct S< S<A...>, C...> {
   int f() {return 2;}
};
```

and when I try to instantiate  `S<S<a, b>, a, b> o2;` compiler complains:

```
prog.cpp:20:21: error: ambiguous class template instantiation for 'struct S<S<a, b>, a, b>'
prog.cpp:6:22: error: candidates are: struct S<A, B, C ...>
prog.cpp:11:33: error:                 struct S<S<A ...>, C ...>
prog.cpp:20:21: error: aggregate 'S<S<a, b>, a, b> o2' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

And when the last specialization is changed to:

```
template<typename... A, typename B, typename... C>
struct S< S<A...>, B, C...> {
   int f() {return 2;}
}
```

everything works fine.

Comment: I think you might add the code in this post as well, as it is very important to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My understanding of the issue:

```
typedef S<S<a, b>, c, d> S2;
```

Here `S<a,b>` matches the second specialization better. However, `c, d` is a better match for the remaining arguments of the first specialization (single arg + list vs list). Hence it is 1:1.

If you comment in `B` in the second specialization, then the second specialization matches better because it is more specialized for the first argument (`S<...>`) and the rest are equally good.

Comment: Nice explanation, +1! Much better than the mess I made.

Comment: Easy to understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I made a mess of this; it should be OK now, but credit is due to @UncleBens below who got it right (and should get the "accept").

---

Without the `B` in your third version, you have two partial specializations which are equally specific when you instantiate `S<S<X,Y,Z>, T1, T2, T3>`:

- First PS: `A = S<X,Y,Z>`, `B = T1`, `C... = T2, T3`.
- Second PS without `B`: `A... = X,Y,Z`, `C... = T1, T2, T3`.
- Second PS with `B`: `A... = X,Y,Z`, `B = T1`, `C... = T2, T3`.

This does not establish comparable elements in the partial specialisation ordering!

Note that you can say `template <typename ...> struct S;` and `template <typename A, typename ...B> struct S<A, B...>;` and the second one is more specific than the first because it has more non-variadic parameters.

But on the other hand, without the `B`, when you say `S<S<X,Y,Z>,T1,T2,T3>`, then the first argument matches better in the second PS, but the remaining arguments match better in the first PS. With the `B` in place, though, the second PS is more specific.

Compare this to the partial specialization that *is* actually more specific:

```
template <typename ...A, typename B, typename ...C>
struct S<B, std::tuple<C...>, std::tuple<C...>> { /* ... */ };
```

Now it is clear how whether a given instance matches the specialization, or only the general form. The specialization has a fixed number of parameters (3), so it wins over another specialization with a variable number of arguments.

Comment: But my specializations are not `<S<A...>, B, C...>` and `<S<A...>, C...>`. They are `<A, B, C...>` and `< S<A...>, C...>` .

Comment: This answer seems wrong, because in your opening example the second specialization seems more specialized than the first. It seems the rule is that `A` trumps `A...`: in OP's question, the second specialization matches the first argument better, but the first specialization matches the second argument better. Hence why it compiles if B is commented in.

Comment: Edited, my first version was blatantly incorrect. Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: @Kerrek SB I appreciate your time and effort.